# ASP:NET Core MVC returns 503

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core (MVC) application. I always get a 503 response back from my request. My code looks like that:

```
public ActionResult Get([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request) {
            if (request.Sorts != null && request.Sorts.Any()) {
                ModifySort<Project>(request.Sorts);
            }
            var result = ctx.Project.Include(x => x.Customer).ToDataSourceResult(request);

            return Ok(result);
}
```

If I debug through my code it look good it goes through everything without throwing an exception it also goes to the result but I still get the 503 response from it.
It is only for that call. Other Functions work even in the same Controller.

Comment: Can you show some mroe code like route config etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything works until the return it is very likely, that your result cannot be serialized.
Make sure, that there are no cyclic dependencies, for example from Project to Customer to Project. You might try this, by setting the Customer in your result-Project to null. You can do the same thing for other Properites if it is not the customer.

Best approach would probably be, to use transfer objects, which you design specifically for your consuming application/... to avoid cylcic dependencies.